# property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use 'Identity' pattern

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, composite-primary-key, hashbytes

I am using Entity Framework database First approach

I have a table having composite primary key on 
ID(int ,identity increment),
HashKey (binary)  auto generated based on multiple columns using sql hashbytes.

Following is EF Column Mapping

ID storeGeneratedPattern="Identity" and 
hashkey(binary) storeGeneratedPattern="Computed".

When i try to save using  EF save changes method it is throwing below exception.

"Modifications to tables where a primary key column has property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use 'Identity' pattern instead. Key column: 'HashKey'. Table"

I have applied composite primary key on these columns(Id,Hashkey) to make search faster as it contains cluster index. But not sure whether EF supports this.

I have seen below link. But i am not sure about the solution.

[Property with StoreGeneratedPattern set to Identity is not updted after SaveChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152736/property-with-storegeneratedpattern-set-to-identity-is-not-updted-after-savechan)

Can anybody help on this to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

'Computed' means EF expects SQL to generate the value after every insert/update.  Therefore it doesn't make sense for it to be part of the PK.

You can just leave the identity as the PK and still create a clustered index with columns(id, hash).

Having said that, it also doesn't make sense to include a computed column in a clustered index.  Every time the computed column is changed, the entire row needs to be moved to the new position.